# CSS Colours not working from Javascript after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a web application and in it I am doing some client-side validation. This is done by adding to each Asp:TextBox

```
onkeyup="javascript: value_change(this);"
```

Once this gets to the value change I have this Javascript...

```
function value_change (text_box) {
    // validate code here
    if (valid) {
        text_box.className = "normalInput";
        document.getElementById("GoButton").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        text_box.className = "errorInput";
        document.getElementById("GoButton").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

The className corresponds to CSS Classes the salient portion of which look like this:-

```
.normalInput
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.errorInput
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

This works fine and dandy when the page is initially displayed, but after the first postback, although the function is invoked, the classname set and the GoButton sensitivity set (I have demonstrated this by stepping through it with debug), the background colours do not change.

Does anyone know why this is and what I should do about it?

**Edit** taking @Pete's advice, I inspected the text_box immediately after the new classname was assigned to it, and it appears that the currentStyle attribute is remaining unchanged. The characteristics of the currentStyle are the same as the normalInput class; I tweaked them and re-ran it to check. So I deduce that the assignment is being ignored, rather than a different CSS working its way in somehow.

Comment: a live example would be nice for debugging this.

Comment: are you using an update panel?

Comment: @Pete, no, there are no update panels in the page.

Comment: @t_virus, sorry I can't help there; this application is for internal use only.

Comment: are you adding the onkeyup attribute in the code behind and if !page.ispostback also I don't think you need to include the javascipt:

Comment: @Pete, thanks for helping; the onkeyup attribute is specified in the Default.aspx file.

Comment: just read your question again and as your classes are being applied that sounds to me that after your page has posted back there may be some overriding style - if you inspect element after the postback it should show you why the background-color isn't changing and which style will be overriding it

Answer (score 0):

Styling changed on the client does not get sent back to the server.  You'd have to set the properties on the server yourself to persist them.  The server builds up the control definition from the set of properties available on the server, and re-renders the original value.  This is because only the value of the textbox posts back to the server; everything else does not.

With that said, you could interpret the conditions to enable or disable the button, and set the appropriate CSS style, and set these properties on the server, or reapply the styles on document load.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the problem is not that the colour change vanishes. The problem is, that before the first postback, entering invalid data into the textbox causes the background colour to change, via the Javascript shown above. After the first postback, entering invalid data causes the Javascript to run but doesn't change the background colour.

Comment: Disabling after postback on a client side solution is best to use the attributes collection as in `Attributes("disabled")`.  Setting Enabled="false" on a .NET control behaves much differently.

Answer (score 0):

After much swearing I finally got the validation to change the background colour after postback as follows:-

```
function value_change (text_box) {
    // validate code here
    if (valid) {
        text_box.className = "normalInput";
        document.getElementById(text_box.name).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        document.getElementById("GoButton").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        text_box.className = "errorInput";
        document.getElementById(text_box.name).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("GoButton").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

I.e by setting it by hand. I don't like this very much as it is driving a coach-and-four throught the whole purpose of the CSS Classes. If someone can come up with something better I am all ears.